# Emacs Theme Colors are wrong

Tags: emacs

I installed Emacs and want to get the atom.io theme, like here:
[GitHub](https://github.com/jonathanchu/atom-one-dark-theme)

The colors should be:
[image: Theme Preview]

And now here is a Screenshot how my colors are looking:
[image: My Emacs]

I also have atom.io installed and the Preview of the sample is correct. Here is my atom.io screenshot:
[image: my atom.io shot]

Finally, my .emacs config file:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
(package-initialize)
(load-theme 'atom-one-dark t)
(require 'powerline)
(powerline-default-theme)
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(custom-safe-themes
   (quote
    ("90d329edc17c6f4e43dbc67709067ccd6c0a3caa355f305de2041755986548f2" "b9c57187960682d4$
 '(desktop-save-mode 1)
 '(global-hl-line-mode 1)
 '(global-linum-mode 1))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

Why are the colors different at my Emacs?
Can this be cause i have the wrong color setup? or why could it be wrong?

Comment: Did you set it up in your emacs init file?

Comment: Are you running Emacs as a graphical application, or inside a terminal like Konsole?

Comment: Graphical application

Comment: Can you run `M-x customize-themes` and see which themes are in use?

Comment: There is just atom-one-dark checked

Comment: What is went wrong on my emacs/os?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, it seems to be a common for Mac users.
I found some help on the issues section on the GitHub page of a similar theme, [dracula](https://github.com/dracula/emacs/issues/2). I followed apierz's fixes to correct the colors on my terminal.

From comparing the dracula theme code with the atom one theme, you can see that both themes use a background of hex color #282*. Basically we need to change the hex color of the background to something more compatible.

Comment out this line of code in your `atom-one-theme.el` file, and add another one with a color value of `nil`.

```
;;; Code:

(deftheme atom-one-dark
  "Atom One Dark - An Emacs port of the Atom One Dark theme from Atom.io.")
(defvar atom-one-dark-colors-alist
  '(("atom-one-dark-accent"   . "#528BFF")
    ("atom-one-dark-fg"       . "#ABB2BF")
;;    ("atom-one-dark-bg"       . "#282C34")
    ("atom-one-dark-bg"       . nil
```

This should make your background the same color as your **terminal window**. Since I have a similar background color to #282C34, mine ends up looking a lot like Atom One Dark Theme.

*Alternatively*, you can set the background color to #000000 (black), however I didn't find it to look too attractive.

*Shoutout to apierz for originally posting the fix on GitHub!*

[what_it_should_look_like.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Muj0j.png)